# Why I get error [PdoException] Couldn't find driver when trying to run doctrine commands in cmd?

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

When I am trying to run command:

```
vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```

in windows command line I am getting this response:

```
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.

  [PDOException]
  could not find driver

orm:validate-schema
```

Why I get error `[PDOException] could not find driver`?

I have `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` uncommented in PHP config. I checked if pdo enabled in php config — it is enabled. `config/autoload/doctrine.local.php` file contents:

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname'   => 'ZF2_Test',
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

- I want to say, that I have module `ZfcUser` and `ZfcUserDoctrineORM` which is needed to connect `DoctrineORM` module and `ZfcUser` module and it is working fine.

So what can cause this error message and error?

Thanks.

P.S.: I am using Windows 8.1, PHP 5.3.27, OpenServer 4.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem, because when I have been running `php ...` from command line it have been using different `php.ini` file. I found this by running this in command line:

```
php --ini
```

I get knowledge, that file is different, uncommented string:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Tried command

```
vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```

again and now everything is fine:

[image: fineee!!!!]